# SPI Isolation : What is the point of the ADuM3151 etc

Tags: spi, isolation

I was looking at ADI's isolators designed and marketed for SPI, such as the [ADuM3151](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum3151.html#product-overview). I'm interested to know what makes these isolators special, in that what the point of them is.

The isolators don't float MISO when the slave is not selected, which I would have thought would be the whole point of an SPI-specific isolation part. Specifically, from the datasheet :

> To allow compatibility with nonstandard SPI interfaces, the MI pin is
>   always active, and does not tristate when the slave select is not
>   asserted. This precludes tying several MI lines together without
>   adding a tristate buffer or multiplexor.

The ADuM3150 has additional circuitry that tries to deal with propagation delay problems on the MISO line (a painful DELAY_CLK approach), but the ADuM3151,2,3 do not even have that. In both cases, to put the isolator onto an SPI bus I still need to look for a tristate buffer with low propagation times to be able to cut off MISO appropriately without adding even more delay.

Additionally, the limited speed of the ADuM3151A, for instance, and its complete disregarding of SS, means I probably wouldn't be able to have a mixed bus with high speed SPI on the non-isolated side without worrying about noisy garbage showing up on the isolated side. The deselected chip select should make sure that the SPI slave does not act improperly, but having all those output drivers trying to push signals that do not need to cross that isolation barrier makes me worried about noise coupling.

Why would I want to use one of the SPI isolators instead of the [ADuM7642](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum7642.html), for example, has considerably better propagation times and should work just as well, if not better, than the ADuM3151 for SPI applications.

Comment: Just use the better device then.

Comment: Speed and isolation seem to be the difference.  3151 is 17MHz and 3.75KV isolation while the 7642 is 25MHz and 1KV isolation.

Comment: The 3151's SPI channels have superior matching for jitter matching between channels and lower propagation delay (your saying the 7642 has a better propagation time is wrong). Also, excessively fast rise times are bad. More noise, ringing, reflections. You don't want or need rise/fall times that can handle 34MHz if you only plan to run your SPI at 17MHz. Simillarly that's why it has three slower channels.